# Upgrade site collections job failing 2013

Tags: 2013, administration, upgrade

I'm currently upgrading some 2010 site collections to 2013. When trying to upgrade it from the GUI, nothing happens and the timer job *Upgrade site collections job* keeps failing over and over again.

Have i done any step wrong in the upgrade process? Everything went smooth when doing the same procedure in my testing environment.

**Edit**

I've done the attach and detach method with success, giving the right accounts permissions, mounted and tested the database without errors and succeed to crawl the site collection in question without any errors, run a site collection health check without errors, and upgraded it to claims as well.

It's when i'm trying to actually do the visual upgrade in the 2013 environment the timer job fails and nothing happens. Sorry for being short on the information.

**Update**

While trying to do the visual upgrade from the UI, running the powershell command upgraded without problem:

`Uppgrade-spsite http://Url/sites/sitecollName -versionupgrade`

Comment: what is the upgrade process you are following?

Comment: See my updated answer above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While trying to do the visual upgrade from the UI, the timer job kept failing and there were no errors in the ULS log.

However running the PowerShell cmd, the site upgraded without problem.

```
Uppgrade-spsite http://WebappUrl/sites/sitecollName -versionupgrade
```